# Custom format of input by user in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to get input from the user in a cell in the format `nn-nn-nn-nn-nnn` (where `n` is any number digit). How can this be done?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. What have you tried so far? Have you looked at custom formatting options already?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on a cell Choose `Format Cells`

Choose Custom

In the text box (where it shows the word General) type  `##-##-##-##-###`

Click OK

Type 12345678901 into the cell and see it is formatted when you leave the cell

[image]

Please note, this doesn't offer any validation or hints. If you were to type abcdefghijk then it won't format, likewise neither will ac12efgh345 will not be automatically formatted either, despite "matching" (aligning) some digits

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells(G2) which you want the condition to be applied on
Format Cell Number Custom and write in the corresponding Box `##-##-##-##-###`
Select again the cells(G2) and set a `Data Validation`, `Custom` in the formula box write:

`=AND(LEN(G2)=11,ISNUMBER(G2))`
You can set `Input Message` like **Write a Whole number with 11 digits**
You can set an `Error Alert` to `Stop` any error entry
You can extend the `Data Validation` and `Custom Format` to several cells

[image]

[image]

**Update**
In case you need digits 0 in the beginning of your number you can change the format number, Custom to:
`0#-##-##-##-###`  in that case you can write `01-02-03-04-005`
and change the Source for the Data Validation to
`=OR(AND(LEN(G2)=11,ISNUMBER(G2)),LEN(G2)=10)`

Comment: What if I have to enter the following value 01020506015

Comment: On entering this value I get 1-02-05-06-015, whereas I want the output to be 01-02-05-06-015. Kindly guide.

Comment: You can use the format 0#-##-##-##-###

Answer (score 0):

For such format Select Cell or range,, Go to the Cell Format, find Custom and you will find,

0###,## and many, find if anyone match your needs otherwise You can Customize it,, write

0#-##-##-##-##-##